# How to reset Quota for API once exceeded in WSO2 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, subscribe, quota, exceed

How I can reset the quota if API access limited?
Suppose we have API subscribe for 1200 request count for three month plan now quota is exceed and we are looking for increase quota for same API and Plan so how to do that without creating new application, or subscription plan in WSO2 APIM

Answer (score 0):

You can reset a subscription policy via WSO2 APIM's Admin Portal.

1. Go to `Subscription Policies` under `Rate Limiting Policies` menu.
2. Click on the edit button in front of the custom subscription policy that you have created.
3. Modify the quota limits as you wish.
4. Click on save button.
5. Now you can access the API with the new changes.

Note that you can observe the following log in carbon logs if the policy is deployed correctly:

```
INFO - EventProcessorDeployer Execution plan is deployed successfully and in active state  : <policy_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't extend or reset a throttle decision in the gateway. When an API is throttled out, the Traffic manager sends an event to the gateway with the throttle decision for the throttle key and when this decision will expire. A sample event is mentioned below.

```
{"event":{"payloadData"{"throttleKey":"1:/pizzashack/1.0.0:1.0.0:5for5mins","isThrottled":true,"expiryTimeStamp":1674491400000}}}
```

Gateway will update it's [throttle data holder](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v9.20.74/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/listeners/JMSMessageListener.java#L133) with this information.

When gateway receives request from the same application, it will check this data holder, see whether expiry time stamp is exceeded, and throttle out.

This data holder entry will persists in memory until you restart the gateway or expiry time exceeds. Therefore even if you update the throttling tier, if the API is already throttled, you can't reset or extend the quota.

Only option would be upgrading the subscription tier to a higher one. Thottle decision is based on the policy and a different policy will act as an extension.